# The method was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy tratando de practicar en Flutter con todo lo relacionado con la internacionalización en un proyecto multilenguaje.

Tras revisar la documentación oficial de [**Flutter**](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) y alguno que otro tutorial encontrado al respecto, he llegado a conformar la estructura de archivos que enumero a continuación para conformar el control del multilenguaje en la aplicación:

- flutt_traducciones_05_01

  - android
  - assets

    - en.json
    - es.json
    - fr.json
  - build
  - ios
  - lib

    - locale

      - app_lang_constant.dart
      - app_localizations.dart
      - initialize_lang.dart
    - src

      - pages

        - home_page.dart
      - my_app.dart
    - main.dart

El contenido de los archivos principales para el funcionamiento de la aplicación es el siguiente:

[assets/lang/**en.json**]

```
{
    "appName" : "Translations - 05.01",

    "homeTitle": "HOME",
    "homeHello": "Hello!! ... Welcome.",
    "homeGreetTo": "Nice to meet you, {{name}}!"
}
```

[assets/lang/**es.json**]

```
{
    "appName" : "Traducciones - 05.01",

    "homeTitle": "INICIO",
    "homeHello": "Aloha!! ... Bienvenido.",
    "homeGreetTo": "¡Encantado de conocerte, {{name}}!"
}
```

[assets/lang/**fr.json**]

```
{
    "appName" : "Traductions - 05.01",

    "homeTitle": "ACCUEIL",
    "homeHello": "Salut!! ... Bienvenu.",
    "homeGreetTo": "Très heureux de faire votre connaissance, {{name}}!"
}
```

[lib/locale/**app_lang_constant.dart**]

```
List<String> languages = ['en', 'es', 'fr'];
```

[lib/locale/**app_localizations.dart**]

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show SynchronousFuture;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutt_traducciones_05_01/locale/app_lang_constant.dart' show languages;


class AppLocalizations {

  final Locale locale;
  final Map<String, Map<String, String>> localizedValues;

  AppLocalizations(this.locale, this.localizedValues);

  static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);
  }

  String get appName {
    return localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['appName'];
  }

  String get homeTitle {
    return localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['homeTitle'];
  }

  String get homeHello {
    return localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['homeHello'];
  }

  homeGreetTo(name) {
    return localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['homeGreetTo']
        .replaceAll('{{name}}', name);
  }

}

class AppLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> {

  Map<String, Map<String, String>> localizedValues;

  AppLocalizationsDelegate(this.localizedValues);

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => languages.contains(locale.languageCode);

  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) {
    return SynchronousFuture<AppLocalizations>(
        AppLocalizations(locale, localizedValues));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(AppLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;

}
```

[lib/locale/**initialize_lang.dart**]

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:flutt_traducciones_05_01/locale/app_lang_constant.dart' show languages;


Future<String> loadJsonFromAsset(language) async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/lang/' + language + '.json');
}

Map<String, String> convertValueToString(obj) {
  Map<String, String> result = {};

  obj.forEach((key, value) {
    result[key] = value.toString();
  });

  return result;
}

Future<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> initializeLang() async {
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> values = {};

  for (String language in languages) {
    Map<String, dynamic> translation =
        json.decode(await loadJsonFromAsset(language));

    values[language] = convertValueToString(translation);
  }

  return values;
}
```

[lib/src/pages/**home_page.dart**]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutt_traducciones_05_01/locale/app_localizations.dart' show AppLocalizations;


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(String) _cambiarIdioma;
  HomePage( this._cambiarIdioma );

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  TextStyle txtStyle = TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25,
                      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          AppLocalizations.of(context).appName + ' - ' + AppLocalizations.of(context).homeTitle,
        ),
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              AppLocalizations.of(context).homeHello,
              style: txtStyle,
            ),
            Text(
              AppLocalizations.of(context).homeGreetTo('Pepe'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => widget._cambiarIdioma('en'),
            tooltip: 'Cambiar de Idioma - EN',
            child: Text('EN',),
          ),
          SizedBox( width: 5, ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => widget._cambiarIdioma('es'),
            tooltip: 'Cambiar de Idioma - ES',
            child: Text('ES',),
          ),
          SizedBox( width: 5, ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => widget._cambiarIdioma('fr'),
            tooltip: 'Cambiar de Idioma - FR',
            child: Text('FR',),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

  }

}
```

[lib/src/**my_app.dart**]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutt_traducciones_05_01/locale/app_localizations.dart' show AppLocalizationsDelegate;
import 'package:flutt_traducciones_05_01/locale/app_lang_constant.dart' show languages;

import 'package:flutt_traducciones_05_01/src/pages/home_page.dart';


class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, Map<String, String>> localizedValues;

  MyApp( this.localizedValues );

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  String _locale = 'en';

  _cambiarIdioma( String localeNew ) {
    setState(() {
      _locale = localeNew;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      title: 'Flutter Traducciones - 05.01',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),

      locale: Locale(_locale),
      localizationsDelegates: [
        AppLocalizationsDelegate(widget.localizedValues),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: languages.map((language) => Locale(language, '')),

      home: HomePage( this._cambiarIdioma(_locale) ),
    );

  }

}
```

[lib/**main.dart**]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutt_traducciones_05_01/src/my_app.dart';
import 'package:flutt_traducciones_05_01/locale/initialize_lang.dart' show initializeLang;

void main() async {
  //Para asegurar la carga demandada antes de lanzar el runApp
  //  -> En este caso, el "loadJsonFromAsset" de initialize_lang.dart
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  Map<String, Map<String, String>> localizedValues = await initializeLang();

  runApp(MyApp(localizedValues));
}
```

Al lanzar la depuración del proyecto para cargar la aplicación en el emulador elegido, no se registra error alguno.
Pero, cuando pulso en uno de los botones para cambiar el idioma en la aplicación, por ejemplo, el de "EN" para establecer el idioma de la aplicación a "Inglés", en la terminal del editor, aparece este mensaje referido a la Excepción que se produjo:

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: call("en")

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutt_traducciones_05_01/…/pages/home_page.dart:50
#2      _InkResponseState._handleTap 
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:706
#3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:789
#4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:182
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#aa1d4
    debugOwner: GestureDetector
    state: ready
    won arena
    finalPosition: Offset(247.2, 638.4)
    finalLocalPosition: Offset(29.8, 27.0)
    button: 1
    sent tap down
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

La misma excepción se produce al pulsar cualquiera de los otros dos botones pero con el correspondiente código de idioma relacionado (sea "es" o "fr").

El método `cambiarIdioma` originalmente, es implementado dentro la clase `_MyAppState` del archivo `lib/src/**my_app.dart**` y es mandado, como parámetro, al constructor de la clase `HomePage` del archivo `lib/src/pages/**home_page.dart**`.

Luego, el método recogido es empleado en las propiedades `onPressed` de los botones pasando el código de idioma correspondiente al que se quiere cambiar la aplicación.
Supuestamente, esta llamada debería ser recibida por el método original de la clase `MyAppState` para que, así, se efectuase el cambio de idioma demandado y el redibujado de la pantalla en el emulador reflejando el cambio de idioma demandado.

Aparte de todo lo comentado, por mi poca experiencia, aún, en Flutter, no sé el por qué del lanzamiento de esta excepción.

Si es posible, por tanto, me gustaría saber el motivo por el cuál se produce esta excepción y, sobre todo, cómo evitar que se produzca y todo llegue a funcionar como es debido.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buscando algo más por Internet, he encontrado un **[ejemplo](https://alligator.io/flutter/widget-communication/)** que me ha ayudado a solucionar el problema.

Los arreglos que he realizado son los siguientes:

[lib/src/pages/**home_page.dart**]

Sustituir esto

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(String) _cambiarIdioma;
  HomePage( this._cambiarIdioma );

  //...
}
```

por esto otro

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(String) cambiarIdioma;
  HomePage({
    @required this.cambiarIdioma
  });

  //...
}
```

[lib/src/**my_app.dart**]

Sustituir esto

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  //...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      //...

      home: HomePage( this._cambiarIdioma(_locale) ),
    );

  }

}
```

por esto otro

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  //...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      //...

      home: HomePage(
        cambiarIdioma: (String loc) { this._cambiarIdioma(loc); },
      ),
    );

  }

}
```

Se admiten otras soluciones mejores si las hubiera.

---

---

Ahora, me gustaría encontrar la forma de poder disponer de archivos de idioma en formato JSON con varias dimensiones (tantas como se deseara), es decir, pasar de como los tengo, por ejemplo, el `es.json`

```
{
    "appName" : "Traducciones - 05.01",

    "homeTitle": "INICIO",
    "homeHello": "Aloha!! ... Bienvenido.",
    "homeGreetTo": "¡Encantado de conocerte, {{name}}!"
}
```

a esto otro:

```
{
    "appName" : "Traducciones - 05.01",

    "home": {
        "title": "INICIO",
        "hello": "Aloha!! ... Bienvenido.",
        "greetTo": "¡Encantado de conocerte, {{name}}!"
    },
}
```

y, por supuesto, poder manejarlo desde el código ya suministrado para poder seleccionar los textos adecuados según el botón de idioma pulsado.

Saludos.